# What moment map is (as a physical concept) in sympletic geometry

Tags: symplectic-geometry, moment-map

What is the intuitive understanding of the moment map in symplectic geometry?

Comment: It's a generalization of momentum. That's why it's called the moment map.

Comment: Trans-duplicate? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203653/intuition-about-momentum-maps